# Airflow installation with sudo doesn't take AIRFLOW_HOME setting

Tags: environment-variables, sudo

I am trying to install AIRFLOW as sudo user to /etc/airflow, here is what I ran and succeed but with a wrong installation folder:

```
sudo su
export AIRFLOW_HOME=/etc/airflow
export SLUGIFY_USES_TEXT_UNIDECODE=yes
pip install apache-airflow
```

So it seems sudo lost the environment setting here, printenv does not have the settings made with sudo.

What am I wrong here?

Thanks.